# ¿Cómo puedo hallar todas las combinaciones de elementos de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una lista (que contiene sólo los números 0 o 1) con una cantidad X de 0, por ejemplo de 4:

```
[0,0,0,0]
```

Y necesito hallar todas las combinaciones posibles con estos números, es decir:

```
[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [1,1,0,0] ........ [1,1,1,1]
```

Pero son muchísimas combinaciones, por lo que no estoy seguro de qué método usar.

He consultado de un método llamado Bitmask el cual me puede resolver el problema, intente  hacerlo con un *for* anidado pero no me fue posible.

¿Existe una forma o algoritmo practico para este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma más básica siempre que la cantidad de `0` y `1` sea acotada podría ser haciendo una comprensión de listas, algo así:

```
elementos = [0,1]
lista = list((x, y, x1, y1) for x in elementos for y in elementos for x1 in elementos for y1 in elementos)
```

Pero en definitiva lo anterior no es más que un [producto cartesiano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano) con repeticiones que podrías resolverlo de manera nativa con [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) de la siguiente forma:

```
from itertools import product
lista = list(product([0,1], repeat=4))
```

#### Importante:

Las dos soluciones entregan un iterador, por lo que es necesario convertirlos en un lista para, por ejemplo, imprimir los valores, pero hay que tener cuidado con esto, ya que es muy fácil cuando trabajamos con combinaciones, permutaciones o productos cartesianos que los elementos generados se nos disparen en cantidad, materializar el resultado en una lista u otro objeto podría reclamarnos la memoria disponible y más, sin mencionar los tiempos necesarios para hacerlo.

Answer (score 5):

La respuésta canónica sería utilizar `itertools.product`, como ya te han indicado en un comentario.

Sin embargo, **sólo como curiosidad**, no he podido evitar implementar esta otra solución, aprovechándome del hecho de que en el fondo todas esas combinaciones de ceros y unos que estás generando pueden leerse como la codificación en binario de todos los números entre 0 y 2**X (siendo `X` el número de "bits" que estás considerando, en tu caso cuatro).

```
def combinaciones_de_X_bits(X=4):
  resultado = []
  fmt = "{:0%db}" % X
  for n in range(2**X):
    binario = fmt.format(n)
    resultado.append(tuple(int(bit) for bit in binario))
  return resultado
```

Insisto en que no es más que una curiosidad. Esta versión es unas 30 veces más lenta que usar `itertools.product`.