# Como puedo sacar todas las combinaciones de un rango?

Tags: python

Ejemplo las combinaciones de 123 serian:
123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.

**Necesito ayuda**

```
def generar():
    def unico(x,L):
        esUnico=True
        for i in range(len(L)):
            if x==L[i]:
                esUnico=False
                break
        return esUnico
    L=[]
    j=0

    while j<6:
        x=random.randint(1,36)
        if unico(x,L):
            L.append(x)
            j+=1
    numero["text"]= L
print(L)
```

El problema es que solo me genera una sola combinacion

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Aquí no hacemos tareas de otros. Muestra lo que has intentado y explica dónde tienes problemas. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará cerrada por falta de un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: El problema está resuelto aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161419/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-hallar-todas-las-combinaciones-de-elementos-de-una-lista?rq=1

Comment: @CandidMoe No es exactamente el mismo problema. En la pregunta que enlazas busca encontrar "palabras" que se puedan formar con un "abecedario" dado, lo cual se resuelve con un producto cartesiano. Pero es no es lo mismo que las permutaciones que es lo que se busca en este caso. En el producto cartesiano aparecerían tambíen como resultados cosas como 111, 222, 333, 122, 221, etc. que aquí no serían válidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mejor no reinventar la rueda cuando la biblioteca estándar python ya te da las herramientas para lograr lo que quieres.

En la biblioteca `itertools` tienes la función `permutations()`. El único problema es que hay que pasarle un iterable (en tu caso las cifras del número), en vez de un número, pero es muy sencillo obtenerlo, basta aplicarle `str()` pues una cadena es un iterable para python.

La función te devuelve otro iterable, y cuando iteras por él, en cada iteración te devuelve una tupla con una permutación diferente. Basta juntar la tupla en una cadena usando `"".join()`.

Si además usas una comprensión de listas para hacer la iteración, puedes lograr lo que buscas con una línea de código:

```
[ "".join(x) for x in permutations(str(numero))]
```

Demo:

```
from itertools import permutations

n = 123
print([ "".join(x) for x in permutations(str(n))])
```

Resultado:

```
['123', '132', '213', '231', '312', '321']
```

Comment: Gracias de verdad